# What exactly is a single "atom" in a standard stream in linux?

Tags: linux, files, linux-kernel, streams

Conceptually, a stream is a sequence of "characters" or "atoms", i.e. a binary stream is a sequence of 0s and 1s. But in Linux standard streams, if I write a bash script that asks "read", then I think it treats a single line (ending with "ENTER") as a "character", but I'm not sure. This suggests to me that a single "atom" is a string, and that atoms are delimited by ENTER. Also, I assume that for other programs, they don't take strings as input, but other data-types.

Am I on the right track? what are the atoms/characters in a standard stream and how does the program know how to carve up a file into atoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, pipes/files/sockets or whatever you have connected stdin/stdout/stderr are streams(*) of *bytes*. The relevant system calls are `read()` and `write()`, and the POSIX descriptions of those say:

> The write() function shall attempt to write nbyte bytes from the buffer pointed to by buf to the file [...]

and

> The read() function shall attempt to read nbyte bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, fildes, [...]

Also, [POSIX defines the byte as being exactly equal to an octet](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_84), that is, a unit of eight bits.

So, an eight-bit byte is the smallest unit you can read or write at a time, so an "atom", if you will.

But what the various utilities do, is a different matter. `read` by default reads a line, but so does the library function `fgets()`. Depending on the shell, you may be able to ask `read` to just read a fixed number of bytes instead, e.g. in Bash:

```
$ echo foo | ( read -n 1 a; echo "first: $a"; read -n 1 b; echo "second: $b" )
first: f
second: o
```

Though note that Bash's `read` obeys the locale and takes the count as *characters*, which could be multi-byte. But that doesn't stop us from reading an individual *byte* instead:

```
$ echo äöä | (read -n 1 a; echo "first: $a"; LC_ALL=C read -n 1 b; echo "second: $b" )
first: ä
second: �
```

(* There are also *datagram* sockets, which still are byte-granular, but also hold boundaries between *messages* (of zero or more bytes) sent in the socket. You could probably plug a properly set up datagram socket to stdin/stdout/stderr, but hardly no-one ever does that.)